# How can the <any>-value be passed as a param in a filtered url for a View?

Tags: views, uri

I have created a View with two exposed filters: name and status. 
The name is a text field, the status is a key|name list: 10|one,20|two,30|three

Using the View as a page, the user can filter the view by entering a text into the name field. The user can filter the status from a dropdown. The dropdown shows 'one' by default because that is the most used filtering.

Everything ok so far.

Now I would like to construct a url as well for this filtering. No problem for the name: view_name?name=richard works perfectly.

For a specific status this also works well: view_name?status=10
(only the key is accepted as a value).

For some views I would like to show all records for one name, whatever the status is. The status defaults to 'one' (which must stay like that) therefore it is not enough to only pass a name. I have to pass something for the status as well.
I tried things like:
view_name?status=
view_name?status=10&status=20 (only last value is used)
view_name?status=0
view_name?status=-1
view_name?status=*
view_name?status=Any

How can I pass the Any-value through the url ?

Answer (score 1):

I suddenly realized that the passed value probably has to match one of the values in the select-options. I just had to look at the source of user page. The value for the Any-option is All. So this works:

```
view_name?status=All
```